# Regex Expression - End search at linebreak

Tags: regex

I am using Regex to search a file and find strings that are "sandwiched" between two other strings. This is my current code:

```
openingstring.*?closingstring
```

The issue I am having is that it is searching across multiple lines in the file. Let's say I want to find anything between "foo" and "bar" and my file looks like so:

```
foo this is NOT the string I want 
foo this is the string I want bar
```

My regex expression is returning both lines, when what I would like is for it to only return line #2.

How can I go about only getting strings where `foo` and `bar` are on the same line?

I should also note that this is not being done in a text editor, or in a programming language necessarily, but in a user interface for automation software.

Comment: Use `^` to designate the beginning of the line and `$` for the end.

Comment: Many regex engines have a multiine mode, usually activated by a 'm' modifier (`/openingsstring.*?closingstring/m`)

Comment: The `^` and `$` are called *anchors*, and you can find information about them in the documentation for whatever regex engine you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the inline modifier `?m`?

`(?m)foo.*bar`

Or, to override `Singleline` mode, `?m-s`:

`(?m-s)foo.*bar`

Comment: @DrydenLong: Great, that just means there was no singleline mode set as default.

Comment: `(?m)foo.*bar` would be enough, no need for "?".

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it really makes a difference in this case. 127 steps vs. just 12! However, we do not know potential input text size... I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

"." is supposed to match any characters except new line, which language are you using?

Anyway, You can try something like this:

```
foo[^\r\n]*bar
```

And note that you don't need "?" where "*" itself means 0 or more.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case where `.*?` can be apparently greedy if it finds foo first, it will just go until it finds the next bar. This is only going to happen, in this case, though, if the dot `.` means Dot-All. You should try to turn that off. Or if you have no choice, use `[^\r\n]*?` instead of the Dot clause `.*?`

Answer (score 0):

The Regex Engine will process Strings from "left-to-right".

Since your input string starts with `foo`, the engine will start to match at that point in the very first attempt. *Nothing* tells the engine, that it should not match the second `foo` with the expression `.*?` - so it proceeds until it finds `bar`:

```
foo .*?                                                         bar
foo this is NOT the string I want foo this is the string I want bar
```

perfect match.

It is always a good idea to *exclude* the *opening* and *closing* String from beeing matched inside the pattern to achieve the shortest possible match:

The pattern `foo((?!foo|bar).)*bar` will match anything between `foo` and `bar` **only** if it does neither contain `foo` nor `bar`:

```
foo((?!foo|bar).)*bar
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cP6mWCi84-h3aJhy)